# Associating secrets based on sub-claims

Tags: abac

In akeyless, is it possible to assign unique secrets to SAML authenticated users based off of ABAC/sub-claim.

for example:

Lets say I have SAML auth users, Jon Smith and Patty Smith. I want to generate an RSA key pair that is unique to each user based on only a sub-claim of `email='first.last@corp.com`

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In Akeyless, you can grant a user or group using a valid auth method that support those params, to get any kind of permission level to even a specific file/folder.
This can be done either via the UI under Access Roles section, or even via the CLI, if you have configured it.
e.g creating the role : `akeyless create-role --name test-role`
associate this role a specific user using email as his sub claim: `akeyless assoc-role-am --role-name test-role --am-name saml-test-auth-method --sub-claims email=barak@yahoo.com` and then specify to which path you would like to grant permission within this role: `akeyless set-role-rule --role-name test-role --path /path/to/specific/secret --capability read`